# if element has className1 classFromArray prepend classFromArray

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the question says I need to do something like:
if element has className1 classFromArray prepend classFromArray.

So far I got this, but it prepends all class names from array that matches, I want it to prepend only the class that it has and matches array.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4c4cnbj/2/)

```
<div class="title purple_grad">
  <p>mensaje</p>
</div>

<div class="title red_grad">
  <p>mensaje</p>
</div>

var cols = [
            'purple_grad',
            'red_grad',
            'green_grad',
            'blue_grad'
];

var e = $("div");
for(i=0; i < cols.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    if ( e.hasClass("title") && e.hasClass(cols[i]) ) {
      e.prepend(cols[i]);
  }
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: Given your html above, what do you want the array to look like in the end? Should it be two elements "purple_grad" and "red_grad"?

Comment: You are iterating `cols` hence in every iteration, 2 items are prepended to the div..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter and prepend the text like

```js
var cols = [
  'purple_grad',
  'red_grad',
  'green_grad',
  'blue_grad'
];

var e = $("div.title"); //the hard filter can be applied here
cols.forEach(function(key) {
  e.filter('.' + key).prepend(key); //prepend the text after applying the class filter
})
```

```css
.purple_grad {
  color: purple;
}
.red_grad {
  color: red;
}
.green_grad {
  color: green;
}
.blue_grad {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title purple_grad">
  <p>mensaje</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="title red_grad">
  <p>mensaje</p>
</div>
```